# Callling object constructor/destructor with a custom allocator

Tags: c++, memory, memory-management, new-operator

I have been looking into custom allocators and I quite often see them using some kind of function to allocate memory. For testing purposes and further educate my self, I tried to make a "simple" example of doing so. However, there is one fundamental thing I am understand on how to do. One of the key differences in `malloc` vs `new` is that with new the constructor is called. What if I wanted to write my own allocator that was essentially replacing `new`, how would I get the constructor to be called when using `malloc`?

I understand that on classes I can overload `new` and `delete` for the class, so I suppose a big part of the question is, how is `new` calling the objects constructor during allocation? Similarly, I am interested in how `delete` is calling the destructor.

I created a sample test code that I was hoping to have the `SomeClass` constructor called during allocation, but I don't see how.

```
#include <malloc.h>

void* SomeAllocationFunction(size_t size) {
    return malloc(size);
}

class SomeClass
{
public:
    SomeClass() {
        int con = 1000;
    }

    ~SomeClass() {
        int des = 80;
    }
};

int main(void){
    SomeClass* t = (SomeClass*)SomeAllocationFunction(sizeof(SomeClass));
    return 0;
}
```

(As a note, I know I can just use `new`. However, for the purposes of learning I am trying to create a custom allocator that does not just call `new` or `placement new`).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In essence, when you use a new expression like: `T *t = new T;`, it's roughly equivalent to:

```
void *temp = operator new(sizeof(T));
T *t = new(temp) T;
```

So, first it allocates some raw memory using the allocation function, then it constructs an object in that memory. Likewise, when you use a delete expression like: `delete t;`, it's roughly equivalent to:

```
t->~T();
operator delete(t);
```

So, if you overload `new` and `delete` for a particular class:

```
class T { 
    int data; 
public:
    // I've made these static explicitly, but they'll be static even if you don't.
    static void *operator new(size_t size) { 
        return malloc(size);
    }
    static void operator delete(void *block) { 
        free(block);
    }
};
```

Then when you use a new expression, it'll invoke the class' `operator new` to allocate the memory, and that will call `malloc`, so `T *t = new T();` will end up allocating memory via `malloc` (and likewise, when you `delete` it, it'll use `operator delete`, which will call `free`).

At least as the term is normally used, an Allocator is quite similar, except that it's used by a container instead of other code. It also encapsulates the allocation function and deletion function into a class, so when you pass one to the container, you only have to pass one object, and there's little chance of an allocation and delete function getting mismatched.

Ignoring, for the moment, the details about what names are used for things, the Allocator class in the standard library *mostly* does the same, so with a little renaming of the functions in the `T` class above, you'd be about half done writing a standard allocator. To go with the allocation and deletion, it has a function to `rebind` some memory (change a block of memory to another type), create an object in place (basically just a wrapper around a placement new) and destroy an object (again, trivial wrapper around destructor invocation). Of course, it uses `operator new` and `operator delete` instead of `malloc` and `free` like I've used above.

Comment: If placement new is what I need to use, then how come for example MSVC's `new` does not call placement new in its version of `new` (in new.cpp, you can get it by stepping into a new call).

Comment: @mmurphy: *Roughly* similar to, definitely not identical to.

Answer (score 10):

With a placement new you can pass an already allocated memory location to the new operator. Then new will construct the object at the given place without doing an allocation on itself.

Edit:

This is how it could be implemented:

```
int main(void){
    // get memory
    void * mem_t = SomeAllocationFunction(sizeof(SomeClass));
    // construct instance
    SomeClass* t = new(mem_t) SomeClass;

    // more code

    // clean up instance
    t->~SomeClass();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The poster said he does not want to call new.

Comment: Constructors don't have a name (opposed to destructors) so they cannot be called directly. A placement new is the only way to properly construct a class instance if you want it to occupy a given memory location.

Comment: I specifically asked without using new.

Comment: @mmurphy `placement new` and `new` are different operators.

Comment: When I said `new` I meant all types of `new`. I updated my question to represent that.

Comment: @mmurphy There is no way to call constructor `SomeClass::SomeClass` without `new` or `placement new`.

Comment: If that is true, then how come for example MSVC's `new` does not call placement new in its version of `new` (in new.cpp, you can get it by stepping into a new call).

Comment: Non-placement version of `new` does follow things. First, it allocates memory (and you saw it in new.cpp, it's part of the RTL). Second, call the constructor of the class (compiler generates this code, you can see it in disassembler). There is no need to call `placement new` from new.cpp

Answer (score 0):

To get the constructor to be called you use placement new(Note you can not override placement new). For delete and all the gotchas well [the FAQ does a good job of explaining it.](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/dtors.html#faq-11.14)

Comment: I specifically asked without using new.

Comment: Yes but placement new is a language primitive, there is no way to implement it in the language.

Comment: @stonemetal: Placement-new is not a language primitive, i.e. `void *operator new (size_t bytes, void *place) { return place; }`