# Use of pointer to vector which involved the use of 'new'

Tags: c++, pointers, vector

I would like to create a *vector of pointers to struct*

```
vector<myStruct*> vec
```

For elements in the vector, not all of them contain data. Some of them may point to **NULL**. 
So, should I create space by `new` in each of the element first

```
for(int i = 0; vec.size() ;i++){
       if (thisSpaceIsValid(i))
             vec.at(i) = new myStruct;
         else
             vect.at(i) = NULL;
}
```

**The problem comes:**
-If I use `new` for each element, it would be very slow. How can I speed it up a bit?  Is there a way the create all the spaces that I need , that automatically access the pointer of such space to the vector(`vec` here)?

-If later I use `delete` to free the memory, would the problem of speed still bother me?

Comment: It may be a good opportunity  for you to learn about smart pointers: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr. If you're using a pre-C++11 compiler you have the same functionality from the boost libraries.

Comment: "If I use new for each element, it would be very slow." *What* would be slow? Initializing the vector? Using it?

Comment: you can still declare a `myStruct tab[max]` if you want to boost the performance but free memory could be delicate then

Comment: If separate allocations is a concern for you, use your own allocation scheme...

Comment: Are you sure that performance of dynamic memory allocation itself is something you should worry about?

Comment: Belt and suspenders programming: the loop runs from 0 to `vec.size()`, so the index `i` will always be in range. But the code also uses `at(i)` in order to make sure?

Comment: @Alain Actually I simplify it, I do use `shared_ptr`

Comment: @NicolBolas I notice when operator `new` used repeatedly in  code, it actually slow down the whole code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If I use "new" for each element, it would be very slow. How can I speed it up a bit? Is there a way the create all the spaces that I need , that automatically access the pointer of such space to the vector("vec" here)?

You can do that.

Let's say the size of your `vector` is `M` and you only need `N` of those elements to have pointers to objects and other elements are null pointers. You can use:

```
myStruct* objects = new myStruct[N];
```

and then, use:

```
for(int i = 0, j = 0; vec.size(); i++)
{
   if (thisSpaceIsValid(i))
   {
      if ( j == N )
      {
         // Error. Do something.
      }
      else
      {
         vec[i]  = objects+j;
         ++j;
      }
   }
   else
   {
      vect[i] = NULL;
   }
}
```

You have to now make sure that you are able to keep track of the value of `objeccts` so you can safely deallocate the memory by using

```
delete [] objects;
```

**PS**

There might be a better and more elegant solution to your problem. It will be worth your while to spend a bit more time thinking over that.

Comment: Is it safe to work with structures in such manner? What's about padding?

Comment: @EdgarRokyan, of course it is safe. The compiler will take care of padding.

Comment: While this is elegant, it leaves us with terrible dilemma of safe and consistent pointer cleanup.

Comment: @SergeyA, I agree. There might be a more elegant solution to the OP's real problem.

Comment: @RSahu, How to create an array similar to `myStruct* objects = new myStruct[N];` with the use of `shared_ptr` instead of ordinary pointer?

Comment: @Carl, use of `shared_ptr` with arrays is not straight forward. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/8947700/434551.

Answer (score 1):

## EDIT:

After reading the question again, it seems I misunderstood the question. So here is an edited answer.

If you only need to execute the code during some kind of initialization phase, you can create all the instances of myStruct in an array and then just point to those from the vector as already proposed by R Sahu. Note that the solution requires you to create and delete all instances at the same time.

However, if you execute this code several times and/or don't know exactly how many myStruct instances you will need, you could overwrite new and delete for the struct and handle memory allocation yourself.

See [Callling object constructor/destructor with a custom allocator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10201214/callling-object-constructor-destructor-with-a-custom-allocator) for an example of this. See the answer by Jerry Coffin.

BTW - you don't need `vec.at(i)` as you are iterating from 0 to size. `vec[i]` is okay and should perform a better.

## OLD ANSWER:

You can do

```
vector<myStruct*> vec(10000, nullptr);
```

to generate a vector with for instance 10000 elements all initialized to nullptr

After that you can fill the relevant elements with pointer to the struct.

For `delete` just

```
for (auto e : vec) delete e;
```

cause it is safe to do `delete`on a nullptr

Comment: As I can understand from the question the problem is the numerous usage of `new` and it's impact to performance. Your answer isn't really helpful in this case.

Comment: @EdgarRokyan - after reading the question again I think your are right. It seems I simply misunderstood the problem. Sh.. happens.

Answer (score 0):

If you need a vector of pointers, and would like to avoid calling new, then firstly create a container of structs themselves, then assign pointers to the elements into your vec. Be careful with choosing the container of structs. If you use vector of structs, make sure to reserve all elements in advance, otherwise its elements may move to a different memory location when vector grows. Deque on the other hand guarantees its elements don't move.

Multiple small new and delete calls should be avoided if possible in c++ when performance matters a lot.

Answer (score 0):

The more I think about it, the less I like @RSahu's solution. In particular, I feel memory management in this scenario would be a nightmare. Instead I suggest using a vector of unique_ptr's owning memory allocated via custom alloctor. I believe, sequential allocator would do.